# How to set "startAt" argument value when using LINQ with Jira Atlassian SDK

Tags: c#, .net, linq, jira-rest-api

As documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home), LINQ queries can be used to fetch issue details from Jira through the Atlassian SDK. However, max issues returned is 1000 per request.
I have tried and went through few similar queries on the web like [this](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Product-Apps-questions/Query-issue-is-limited-to-20-issues/qaq-p/28726) on how can you change the default value of "startAt".

Also, GetIssuesWithJqlAsync method does provide capability to modify the "startAt" value. Any way to override its default value through LINQ?

Comment: Normmaly if you want to get your information divided in "pages" of size S, you can get page P using OrderBy / Skip / Take: OrderBy(...).Skip(P*S).Take(S). Can't you use this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Skip(n)` to skip items in an enumerable with **Linq**.

`Skip(1000 * page).Take(1000)` would work for you.

[MSDN on Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ allows you to use

```
item.Skip(n);
item.Take(n);
```

You can define where to start taking results from the resultant query.